# Freezing after installation Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, freeze

Ubuntu was installed to my competer as second operating system. But after installation, I entered my password then it was freezed. I can move my mouse. But everything on the screen is like part of wallpaper. There is no response.

My Computer= Lenovo y520, gtx 1050 ti, intel i7 7700HQ

EDIT= windows is installed at ssd so I installed Ubuntu at hdd.

Comment: Does it happen every time after login?

Comment: Yes, sometimes It is freezed before login